# A technique of using similar sounding words, instead of swear words

Tags: word-request, slang, euphemism

What is called a technique or method of using similar sounding words, instead of swear words in a sentence? For example:

> I'm not going to invite that mother trucker or mother father to the party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *minced oath* a form of *euphemism* which is sometimes done to *bowdlerise* a text.

To "mince" is being used in an archaic sense of "make very small". There are many ways to mince an oath, but using similar-sounding words is a common one.  "Oath" is also being used in an old-fashioned way. Many would not consider sexual swear words to be "oaths" in the normal sense. But many of the old taboo words were related to God or Jesus.